# Handling a special case during tail -f logging

Tags: bash

I am tailing the logs  to find if there is any Exception as show below

```
tail -f flexi.log | grep "Exception" --color
```

This works fine , but unfortanely i dont want to log it incase if there s any DataNotAvailableException .

The DataNotAvailableException comes frequently and i dont want to log that .

Is this possible ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add another grep to search and remove the DataNotAvailables.

```
tail -f flexi.log | grep "Exception" --color | grep -v "DataNotAvailableException"
```